# Limiting authorization scope to specific calendar

Tags: google-calendar-api

My goal is to add client-specific events to client's calendar (imagine doctor appointments). If The client has to authorize my application with either **/auth/calendar** or **/auth/calendar.events**, but the authorization request always asks for access to the whole calendar (or all of calendar's events).

My specific intent is to **create "doctor_appointments" sub-calendar** in the clients' calendar and have the **authorization scope limited to that sub-calendar**, for security.

Is this currently possible? And is my approach correct?

Comment: When you get access you get full access to the calendar. Have you considered creating a new calendar?

Comment: I have, but I never want the client to have to grant me full access, it seems like overkill, potentially dangerous. (as I understand, full access allows manipulating with all existing calendars and events)

Comment: Why not create a calendar as the doctor, and share it with the patient only, modifying it with their client-specific events?

Comment: Hmm it seems to be the better idea. I will look into that, thanks for tolerating a wide question like that.
In your scenario, would I need to create a separate calendar for every patient, or can I put all events into one calendar and share only client-specific events with each patient?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer your comment's question:

You can do both options whichever turns out more comfortable for you or the doctors workflow. For example, they could have a calendar for each doctor in the office, and thus know when they are busy/free, then they can allocate clients (create events and invite patient) to that doctor's calendar.